# local.xml points to local host but magento says it's on old server

Tags: database, local.xml

I recently moved a magento website for a friend. The old local.xml pointed to the old server IP address so I corrected this on the new site to point to localhost. Everything worked fine and seem to be using the DB on the new server as the account on the old server was suspended.

1 day later the old server was taken offline and the database no longer works, seems it was still pointing to the old server. I've cleared the cache, made sure the compiler was turned off and deleted the sessions with no luck.

Here the local.xml to provide any aid

```
<connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[<DB User>]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[<password>]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[<DB Name>]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
```

Comment: are you sure you cleared the cache properly? I mean if you have APC or memcached those need to be cleared also. Also check maybe the cache is not writtern in `var/cache` folder of Magento. If that's not writeable Magento will use `/tmp` folder of the system.

Comment: I have SSH access and cleared the cache via rm -rf var/cache/*. I couldn't find a /tmp under the root magento directory.

Comment: Don't look for `/tmp` in the magento instance.  Look for it in the file system. `/tmp` it's an absolute path, not relative to your install.

Comment: That tmp is empty

Comment: If there is no memcache or APC (or any other cache-ing system ) involved, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Once you flushed `var/cache` was anything re-created there?

Comment: Nothing was re-created

Comment: In the terminal (SSH), can you connect to the database using the settings in the `local.xml`? For example: `mysql -h localhost -u dbuser -pdbpass`. Also, are you absolutely sure it's the database that doesn't work? What msgs are you getting?

Comment: I can confirm that I can access the database and it's not empty. The error messages always say can't connect sql on <IP of old server>

Comment: I have a question how can i add SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in this sentence <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>

Comment: <pdoType><![CDATA[SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1]]></pdoType>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve the issue.

There a plugin on the website has a DB connection file. This file was also pointing to the old server and seems to be overwritting the local.xml

Once this was updated the site was working again.

Comment: Also, if there are any other .xml files in the app/etc/ folder, they will be included in the Magento runtime and can be the source of such issues.

Comment: Already been suggested - see my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought would be to make sure you don't have the local.xml configuration data in any other .xml files in the app/etc/ directory.  It doesn't have to be called local.xml, Magento will just use the last instance of the config data it finds in any .xml file from that directory.

So for instance if you have have copied local.xml with the old data to oldlocal.xml in this same directory to back it up, because oldlocal.xml comes after local.xml alphabetically it loads last, thus you get the configuration data from oldlocal.xml, not local.xml.

Comment: We only have one local.xml

Comment: Ok, what other .xml files do you have in that directory?

Comment: config.xml, local.xml, local.xml.additional, local.xml.template

Comment: Ok, well seems like some code diving may be the next step!

Comment: Do you need the local.xml code?

Comment: Not sure it will help, but probably worth posting in your initial question for the sake of completion.